# Use addFieldToFilter on order object to get orders of specific user

Tags: magento2, module

I'm trying to access the order object and return some information.

My block is called `Review.php`.

```
<?php

namespace MS\RealReviews\Block;

/**
 * Entity rating block
 *
 */

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView
{

    protected $customer_id;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(    
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
             $context, 
             $urlEncoder,
             $jsonEncoder,
             $string,
             $productHelper,
             $productTypeConfig,
             $localeFormat,
             $customerSession,
             $productRepository,
             $priceCurrency,
             $collectionFactory,
             $data
        );
    }  

    public function getOrders() {

        if (!$this->orders && !$this->customer_id):
            $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'customer_id',
                $this->_getCustomerID()
            );
        endif;

        return $this->orders;

    }

    protected function _setCustomerID($input){
        $this->customer_id = $input;
    }

    protected function _getCustomerID(){
        return $this->customer_id;
    }

    public function isRealReview($customer_id = false){

        $html = '';
        $product = $this->getProductId();


        if($customer_id):
            $this->_setCustomerID($customer_id);
        endif;

        $orders = $this->getOrders();
        if($orders && count($orders)):
            foreach($orders as $_order):
                foreach($_order->getAllItems() as $item):
                    $html .= "1"; // get item arrays further...
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
        endif;

        $html .= $this->_getCustomerID();

        return $html;
    }

}
```

I want to get the items of all orders for a specific user. Right now, my block is failing, there is no output on the frontend.

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

I needed to change the way I initiate the `getOrders` function.

```
public function getOrders() {

        if (!$this->orders && $this->customer_id):
            $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'customer_id',
                $this->_getCustomerID()
            );
        endif;

        return $this->orders;

    }
```

additionally to that, there was the property `$orders` missing, so I've added it. Final file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace MS\RealReviews\Block;

/**
 * Entity rating block
 *
 */

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView
{

    protected $customer_id;
    protected $orders;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(    
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
             $context, 
             $urlEncoder,
             $jsonEncoder,
             $string,
             $productHelper,
             $productTypeConfig,
             $localeFormat,
             $customerSession,
             $productRepository,
             $priceCurrency,
             $collectionFactory,
             $data
        );
    }

    public function getOrders() {

        if (!$this->orders && $this->customer_id):
            $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'customer_id',
                $this->_getCustomerID()
            );
        endif;

        return $this->orders;

    }

    protected function _setCustomerID($input){
        $this->customer_id = $input;
    }

    protected function _getCustomerID(){
        return $this->customer_id;
    }

    public function isRealReview($customer_id = false){

        $html = '';
        $product = $this->getProductId();


        if($customer_id):
            $this->_setCustomerID($customer_id);
        endif;

        $orders = $this->getOrders();
        if($orders && count($orders)):
            foreach($orders as $_order):
                foreach($_order->getAllItems() as $item):
                    $html .= "1";
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
        endif;


        //$html .= $this->getOrders(); 
        $html .= $this->_getCustomerID();


        return $html;
    }

}
```